# Python 3: Should typing hints generated with boto3-stubs be commited to VCS?

Tags: python, boto3, gitignore, python-typing

I have ran `boto3-stubs` to generate type hints for `boto3`, following [this guide](https://pypi.org/project/boto3-stubs/#usage) 
for PyCharm. As expected, `mypy_boto3_builder` has created a `typings` directory with all the `.pyi` files. Should I commit these files to my git repository or add them to `.gitignore`? Unfortunately, the guide doesn't mention anything it this regard.

My intuition tells me to ignore them and let any other collaborators on my project generate them for themselves if they need it. Is there a best practice I am missing?

Comment: depends if you are alone on the project or not ? If not, other devs are using the same tools ?

Comment: Other devs are likely to use the same tools but not necessarily.